# Max in linq to NHibernate for not exist data in database

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, max, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query by linq to NHibernate.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Request>().Max(e => e.Code);
```

If `Request` table has no rows, execution of this query raises GenericADOException with this message :

`{"Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]"}`

`{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: item"}`

What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
SessionInstance.Query<Request>().Max(x => (int?)x.Code);
```

Comment: Why does the cast make this work? Was `x.Code` something else than `int?`? (I just want to learn, not promoting my own answer).

Comment: @GertArnold I don't know, it just works:) But i think that it is something related to Nhibernate linq provider.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Your Max function might return null if for example there is no rows in the database table, therefore  you casting it properly `(int?)x.Code`. There's gonna be no difference in generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work with Linq-to-Nhibernate:

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Request>().Select(e => e.Code)
    .DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

or maybe `DefaultIfEmpty(<some value>)`.

Comment: Your solution for many records in database for performance is not suitable.

Comment: Why not? DefaultIfEmpty will not fetch more records, it will only add a value if the sequence is empty.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty for NHibernate linq provider is not implemented and throws exception as of NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 version

Comment: Indeed - "The DefaultIfEmptyResultOperator result operator is not current supported"